# C++. Why code using classes is slower than using functions?

Tags: c++, performance

in the simple program below, there is a C++ version in class `Gaps` of the algorithm, and a C version<sup>1</sup> of the code.

The code gets some integer values in `VALUES` and tries to find left-shifts of these values so they can be `or`ed in such a way that the result has all bits set, and the shifted values don't overlap bit-wise.

For example, the first result for `VALUES` of 101<sub>2</sub>, 1001<sub>2</sub>, 10001<sub>2</sub>, ... , 1000000001<sub>2</sub> is printed as

```
Solution 1
|101.............|
|.........1001...|
|..........10001.|
|...100001.......|
|.1000001........|
|....10000001....|
|.....100000001..|
|......1000000001|
```

The rows represent the shifted values. The 1st row is 101<sub>2</sub> ≪ 13, the 2nd row is 1001<sub>2</sub> ≪ 3 etc.  Each column contains exactly one `1`.

My C++ compiler is g++ v11.3, and the source code is compiled as

```
> g++ -O3 gaps.cpp -o gaps.x -Wall -fno-exceptions
```

The C++ version can be run by `time ./gaps.x c++ 0` which generates all possible solutions and print 0 of them.

The C-ish version can be run by `time ./gaps.x c 0` which also generates all possible solutions without printing any of them.

With my laptop I am getting the following (rounded user) exection times:

```
C   0m0.75s
C++ 0m1.30s
```

So the C++ version is considerably slower than the C-ish. This pattern persists when I add 11<sub>2</sub> to `VALUES`:

```
C   0m58s
C++ 1m36s
```

**Question**: Why the C++ version is so much slower than C paradigm? 99% of the code is setting, adding, oring, comparing integers.  For each method like `Gaps.is_solution()` there is a C function like `is_solution()`. The ony difference in the code is that the C++ code has to dereference `this`; is this really so expensive?

---

<sup>1</sup> All parts of the code are C++ of course because they are compiled with `g++`.

---

[Code in godbolt.org compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/h3bjYdexq)

```cpp
// Finding solutions for Enigma, Level Pack XI, "Gaps".

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

#define VALUES                                               \
    0b101, 0b1001, 0b10001, 0b100001, 0b1000001, 0b10000001, \
    0b100000001, 0b1000000001,                               \
    // 0b11

unsigned print_n_solutions = -1u;
    
// Integral part of log_2(N).
static int ilog2 (unsigned n)
{
    return (n == 0)
        ? -1
        : 8 * sizeof(n) - __builtin_clz(n) - 1;
}

// Numer of bits needed to represent N.
static int width (int n)
{
    assert (n % 2 == 1);
    return 1 + ilog2 (n);
}

static const char* to_bin (int n)
{
    static char str[65];
    char *s = str;

    for (int i = ilog2 (n); i >= 0; --i)
        *s++ = '0' + (n >> i) % 2;
    *s = '\0';
    
    return str;
}


class Gaps
{
    const std::vector<int> values_;
    const int n_values_;
    const int n_bits_;
    const std::vector<int> widths_;
    std::vector<int> shifts_;

    // Helper to initialize .n_bits_.
    int get_n_bits() const
    {
        int bs = 0;
        for (auto v : values_)
            bs += __builtin_popcount (v);
        return bs;
    }

    // Helper to initialize .widths_.
    std::vector<int> get_widths_() const
    {
        std::vector<int> ws;
        for (auto i : values_)
            ws.push_back (width(i));
        return ws;
    }

public:
    Gaps (std::initializer_list<int> vs)
        : values_(vs), n_values_((int) vs.size()), n_bits_(get_n_bits()),
          widths_(get_widths_()),
          shifts_(std::vector<int>(n_values_))
    { }

    Gaps (const Gaps&) = delete;
    Gaps (Gaps&&) = default;

    void print_solutions()
    {
        unsigned n_solutions = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n_values_; ++i)
            shifts_[i] = 0;

        do
        {
            if (is_solution())
                if (++n_solutions <= print_n_solutions)
                    print_solution (n_solutions);
        } while (next());
    }

private:
    bool is_solution () const
    {
        int bits = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n_values_; ++i)
        {
            int b = values_[i] << shifts_[i];
            if ((bits & b) == 0)
                bits |= b;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    bool next()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_values_; ++i)
        {
            ++shifts_[i];
            if (shifts_[i] + widths_[i] > n_bits_)
                shifts_[i] = 0;
            else
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void print_solution (unsigned n_solutions) const
    {
        static const char *blank = "................................";
        printf ("\nSolution %u\n", n_solutions);
        for (int i = 0; i < n_values_; ++i)
            printf ("|%.*s%s%.*s|\n",
                    n_bits_ - widths_[i] - shifts_[i], blank,
                    to_bin (values_[i]), shifts_[i], blank);
    }
};

#define ARRAY_SIZE(X) (sizeof(X) / sizeof(*X))

#define n_values ((int) ARRAY_SIZE (values))

const int values[] = { VALUES };

static int n_bits;
static int shift[n_values];
static int widths[n_values];

bool next (void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_values; ++i)
    {
        ++shift[i];
        if (shift[i] + widths[i] > n_bits)
            shift[i] = 0;
        else
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void print_solution (unsigned n_solutions)
{
    static const char *blank = "................................";
    printf ("\nSolution %u\n", n_solutions);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_values; ++i)
        printf ("|%.*s%s%.*s|\n", n_bits - widths[i] - shift[i], blank,
                to_bin (values[i]), shift[i], blank);
}

bool is_solution (void)
{
    int bits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n_values; ++i)
    {
        int b = values[i] << shift[i];
        if ((bits & b) == 0)
            bits |= b;
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void print_solutions (void)
{
    unsigned n_solutions = 0;
    do
    {
        if (is_solution())
            if (++n_solutions <= print_n_solutions)
                print_solution (n_solutions);
    } while (next());
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 2)
        sscanf (argv[2], "%u", &print_n_solutions);

    if (argc > 1 && !strcasecmp ("c", argv[1]))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_values; ++i)
            n_bits += __builtin_popcount (values[i]);

        for (int i = 0; i < n_values; ++i)
            widths[i] = width (values[i]);
    
        print_solutions();
    }

    if (argc > 1 && !strcasecmp ("c++", argv[1]))
    {
        Gaps { VALUES }.print_solutions();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post a separate code block for your C code. We can't divine the C code because your C++ code uses C++ constructs like `std::initializer_list`, `std::vector`, `for (auto i : values_)`, etc. You may need to benchmark individual sections of the code to find the bottlenecks. For example, `std::vector` doesn't exist in C, so the array equiv (e.g. `int *arr; size_t arrcnt;`) could be faster for "pushing" onto it.

Comment: Classes and vectors vs functions and static arrays. All your code is C++. There is no C vs C++ in your code.

Comment: You are building your programs using no optimization options which means -O0. Enable optimizations.

Comment: @digito_evo: When I read the question I see `g++ -O3 gaps.cpp -o gaps.x -Wall -fno-exceptions` which definitely is not `-O0`.

Comment: @0___________: Yes, it's all C++ as I already noted.  One part of the Code is C++ paradigm (uses class and methods and constructing) whereas the other part is C paradigm.  Using the same compiler is more striking because some of GCC's optimization are performed by the language front-ends.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yeah right. I missed it.

Comment: Try introducing a non-type template parameter, `Gaps<n_values> { VALUES }.print_solutions()` and get rid of the resizable vectors.

Comment: @Craig Estey: The question is rather C-ish style vs. C++ style, as I noted all is C++ as compiled by `g++`. Using the same compiler is more striking because some of GCC's optimization are performed by the language front-ends. Allocation happens only once, and I don't expect for allocating thess than 100 bytes once can take 30 seconds?

Comment: *"One part of the Code is C++ paradigm"*  But you forgot to create the class object using `new` and make all the member functions `virtual` . :-)

Comment: "Allocation happens only once" True, but you pay for the lack of memory locality over and over again.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts profile the program yourself and you will get the answer instantly. You will know where the bottlenecks are. Why do you think I should do it for you?

Comment: Interesting problem.  You should **profile** the code to see why it differs.  I noticed that the "C++" (using a class, takes about 5 seconds to run) logic output seems to pause every few dozen outputs, but the "C" (procedural, takes about 2.5 seconds to run) logic output runs smoothly.  That's suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a fair comparison because the compiler is allowed to generate far better code for the C version. This is because the C code gets to see in `VALUES` and `n_values` at compile-time, whereas the C++ code has to do heap allocations, pointer arithmetics, and iterate over a non-compile-time `n_values_`.

When the compiler sees that the `VALUES` is a compile-time constant it is allowed to generate this kind of code for the C `print_solutions` (many parts omitted for brevity):

```
print_solutions():
    ...
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR shift[rip]
    mov     esi, DWORD PTR shift[rip+4]
    mov     edi, DWORD PTR shift[rip+8]
    mov     r8d, DWORD PTR shift[rip+12]
    mov     r9d, DWORD PTR shift[rip+16]
    mov     r10d, DWORD PTR shift[rip+20]
    mov     r11d, DWORD PTR shift[rip+24]
    mov     r12d, DWORD PTR shift[rip+28]
.L2:
    mov     ecx, edx      ; 1st iteration of is_solution
    mov     eax, ebp
    mov     r13d, 9
    sal     eax, cl
    mov     ecx, esi
    sal     r13d, cl
    test    eax, r13d
    jne     .L3
    or      eax, r13d     ; 2nd iteration of is_solution
    mov     ecx, edi
    mov     r13d, 17
    sal     r13d, cl
    test    eax, r13d
    jne     .L3
    ...
main:
    ...
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC10[rip]     ; Precalculated widths[0...3]
    add     DWORD PTR n_bits[rip], 16        ; Precalculated n_bits
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR widths[rip], xmm0    ; Updating widths global
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC11[rip]     ; Precalculated widths[4...7]
    movaps  XMMWORD PTR widths[rip+16], xmm0 ; Updating widths global
    call    print_solutions()
    ...
```

`gcc` has basically gone and determined that:

1. global array `shift` is not changed outside of the loop, thus it can just be converted to a bag of integer registers.
2. The `is_solution` algorithm can be entirely unrolled to a bunch of moves and shifts acting on registers.
3. `VALUES, n_bits` and `widths` can all be injected into the generated assembly as constants.

Meanwhile, the C++ variant has to:

1. Allocate memory with `new` for the three `std::vector<int>` members.
2. Calculate `n_bits, shift` and `widths` iterating element-by-element.
3. Perform pointer arithmetic and memory loads each time an element is dereferenced (eg. `shifts[i]`)

Considering these differences it is no surprise that the C++ code is quite a bit slower. The C `ìs_solution` gets unrolled shifts over integer registers, whereas `Gaps::is_solution` loop is compiled to a plain element-by-element for-loop. I will not bore you with the assembly here, but if you are interested check the [OP's godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/h3bjYdexq). After all, there is a reason why the `std::vector`'s `operator[]` takes around 12 % of the execution time according to kcachegrind:

[image: kcachegrind profiler results]

Some of the comments already pointed out some things you could have done to make the implementations equivalent. It all basically boils down to:

1. Make `VALUES` visible to the `Gaps` class as a compile-time array
2. Convert size (`n_values_`) to a compile-time constant.
3. Replace `std::vector<int>` with `std::array<int, N>`
4. Make `_widths` and `shifts_` global, much like the C variants are.

**An example of a modified `Gaps` class is [available here](https://godbolt.org/z/sjWKa94oY)**. Naturally, with these changes you lose quite a lot of flexibility in the `Gaps` class, but the purpose of this answer was to address the performance differences. If the `VALUES` is always known at compile-time and you have many of them, you could, for example, template `Gaps` with a non-type template parameter `std::size_t` to achieve a bit more flexibility.

With these changes the C and C++ methods are equivalent in terms of performance and implementation:

```
$ time ./profile c 0

real    0m0.229s
user    0m0.229s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./profile c++ 0

real    0m0.233s
user    0m0.233s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed analysis.  I had a look at the generated asm but was overwhelmed as I am not experienced in x86 at all.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts That is completely understandable. I have been and will continue to get overwhelmed by compiler-generated code. With experience, you will start to recognize certain patterns. I guess the key takeaway here is that having anything known at compile-time vs. not, you can be sure that the compiler will take advantage of it.